# CSS animation don't work as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

Check the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/naexywf8/

As you can see, the 3 elements appears at different moments, but the first 2 it's like they "crash" and just the 3rd one does the animation perfectly.

If anyone could give me a solution so the first 2 element don't crash, specially if this class remains untouch (this is because there are a lot of css extra lines and it will be awful to fix that)

```
.intro_video, .blackDiv, .intro_button{}
```

Comment: kindly include relevant code to the OP dont just post link for demo because link rot.. You can use snippet in SO

Comment: sorry, post edited :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gf5L4xeo/

try this one, the src for video url is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more height in container, otherwise adding elements causes jumpy behavior.

```
.intro_video{
    height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/naexywf8/1/